# Add Solr script on startup

Tags: linux, centos

I am trying to run `Solr` on startup or automatically on a [VPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server) with [CentOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) 6.0, and I have read the answers in Stack Overflow question *[How to start Solr automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150767/how-to-start-solr-automatically)*.

And I could not execute this to the required solution.

At first, I created a `.sh` file with a [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job, and it's not working. I also tried the other answers too, but I could not figure out why shell script doesn't run.

And I even tried executing it directly by the below commands.

```
sh solr_startup.sh
sh solr_startup.sh
```

But I got an error that
    1. Cannot find the directory
    2. Cannot execute the Java file and script code below

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /opt/solr/example/solr/example
java -jar start.jar
```

Note: `/opt/solr/example` is my Solr home directory.

Is there a way to create a cron or automated job or a file that can run on startup?

Comment: Is that the entire contents of your shell script?

Comment: yes, except the Note

Comment: Does the directory in your shell script actually exist?

Comment: Yes. I can execute each every command mentioned above..

Comment: Okay, It just got executed, now how to place in startup, i tried to place in `/etc/init.d/`

Comment: move your shell script under the directory `/etc/init.d/`. Make sure it's executable, then add the line `/etc/init.d/whatever_your_script_name_is` to `/etc/rc.local`.  See if that works for you.

Comment: Yes! did, actually i am working on VPS Server from PuTTY

Comment: Okay, So the file is added on startup and how do i need to restart the VPS server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also start your script up from `/etc/rc.local`.

First make sure the directory in your shell scripts exists and that it runs without errors. If it does, be sure to make it executable by running the command `chmod a+x script_name`.

Move your shell script under the directory `/etc/init.d/`. Add the following line `/etc/init.d/script_name` to `/etc/rc.local`. Reboot, check that your service has started.